# Github commited files bulk open with text editor

Tags: github, sublimetext3, text-editor, github-desktop

How can I open all this files in sublime? I mean bulk open. this is 100+ files and it consumes a lot of time opening it one by one.
[image]

One by one opening consumes time
[image]

Comment: Do you have the list of files in text format? Just pass them to `subl`.

Comment: Yes. but is there a way on github desktop to bulk open this files in sublime or any text editor?

Comment: You didn't indicate that you wanted to open them via the Github Desktop interface. I'm not very familiar with that program, but can you use `Ctrl-A` or Shift-click to select multiple files from the interface you're in, then right-click and choose Open in Sublime Text?

Comment: It is not working when the files are already commited .